# Android TextViews overlap

Tags: android, textview, overlap

I have a RelativeLayout with several TextViews with dynamic content that overlap in some cases:[image: Overlappping TextViews]

The first example is the problematic one, the other two ones are correct. The preferred solution for the first one would be a line break for the date. But I was not able to solve this and at the same time to keep the two other examples at 2 lines for the 3 TextViews. (Since the text is dynamic, all 3 examples have to have the same Xml source code)

I have made an example Xml with static content to test it in the Design editor:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical">

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="7dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/tl_team_image"
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tl_team_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tl_team_image"
        android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur"
        android:textSize="60sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tl_location_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tl_team_view"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tl_team_image"
        android:text="Location Number 1"
        android:textSize="50sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tl_place_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tl_team_view"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tl_location_view"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="Some Very Longplace"
        android:textSize="50sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tl_date_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tl_location_view"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tl_team_image"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp"
        android:text="Tomorrow (August 31, 4 p.m.)"
        android:textSize="50sp"/>
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="7dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/tl_team_image2"
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tl_team_view2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tl_team_image2"
        android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur"
        android:textSize="60sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tl_location_view2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tl_team_view2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tl_team_image2"
        android:text="Location Number 1"
        android:textSize="50sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tl_place_view2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tl_team_view2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tl_location_view2"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="A Short Place"
        android:textSize="50sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tl_date_view2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tl_location_view2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tl_team_image2"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp"
        android:text="Tomorrow (August 31, 4 p.m.)"
        android:textSize="50sp"/>
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="7dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/tl_team_image3"
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tl_team_view3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tl_team_image3"
        android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur"
        android:textSize="60sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tl_location_view3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tl_team_view3"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tl_team_image3"
        android:text="Location Number 1"
        android:textSize="50sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tl_place_view3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tl_team_view3"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tl_location_view3"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="Some Very Longplace"
        android:textSize="50sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tl_date_view3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tl_location_view3"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tl_team_image3"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp"
        android:text="September 21, 4 p.m."
        android:textSize="50sp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your third  `TextView`. It should be placed below **second** `textview` while currently you have it below **first** `textview` and hence overlaps, and same applies for your **4th** `textview`

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/tl_team_image"
    android:layout_width="65dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tl_team_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tl_team_image"
    android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur"
    android:textSize="60sp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tl_location_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tl_team_view"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tl_team_image"
    android:text="Location Number 1"
    android:textSize="50sp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tl_place_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tl_location_view"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tl_location_view"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:text="Some Very Longplace"
    android:textSize="50sp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tl_date_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tl_place_view"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tl_team_image"
    android:paddingBottom="2dp"
    android:text="Tomorrow (August 31, 4 p.m.)"
    android:textSize="50sp"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I do want to have the third TextView (place) to the right of the 2 other TextViews, so that I have 3 TextViews using only 2 lines total. Only in the first example it does not fit and should automatically use 3 lines.

Comment: Then use linear layouts with weights

Comment: It seems that LinearLayout can make only either example 2 or example 3 to work. The other example would then need 3 lines. Not to speak about example 1.